# What is the correct scope to declare a variable that needs to be remembered while looping?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, scope

Beginner at JavaScript here. Below is a JS challenge I've just completed for a course. The challenge:

`Clean the room function: given an input of [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20], make a function that organizes these into individual array that is ordered. For example answer(ArrayFromAbove) should return: [[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2], 4,5,10,[20,20], 391, 392,591]`

My solution:

```
let originalArray = [1,2,4,591,392,391,2,5,10,2,1,1,1,20,20];

const compareFunction = ((a, b) => {
    return a-b;
});

let counter = 1;

const groupFunction = (currentValue, index, arr) => {
    nextNumber = arr[index + 1];
    if (currentValue === nextNumber){
        counter++;
    } else {
        if (counter > 1){
            let filledArray = new Array(counter).fill(currentValue);
            counter = 1;
            return filledArray;
        } else {
            return currentValue;
        }
    }  
};

const filterFunction =  (currentValue) => {
    return currentValue !== undefined;
}

const finalFunction = (arr) => {
    arr.sort(compareFunction);
    let groupedArray = arr.map(groupFunction);
    let finalArray = groupedArray.filter(filterFunction);
    return finalArray;
}

finalFunction (originalArray);
```

Everything returns correctly, however I am under the impression that it is bad practice to declare global variables. With my "counter" variable, if I assign it within the groupFunction, the counter resets every loop through the array, making it useless. Where would be the appropriate place to put this variable? Is there another method / approach that would be better suited for the problem all together? Thank you!

Comment: Do you need to use `map` and `filter`? With a conventional loop this would be much easier.

Comment: You should declare the `counter` inside `finalFunction`, as that's where you need to initialise it to 1 every time, and you need to declare the `groupFunction` inside `finalFunction` as well so that it gets access to the local `counter`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a much shorter approach, that I know as beginner will have you searching to learn what some of the stuff used does, if you did not learn about it already.

Stay Curious.

```
const finalFunction = (arr) => {
  const map = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = (acc[curr] || 0) + 1;
    return acc;
  }, {});
  return Object.keys(map)
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .reduce((acc, val) => {
      const value = Number(val);
      acc.push(map[val] > 1 ? Array(map[val]).fill(value) : value);
      return acc;
    }, []);
};
```

And another one:

```
const finalFunction = (arr) =>  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
      const last = acc.pop();
      return curr === last
        ? [...acc, [curr, curr]]
        : last && curr === last[0]
        ? [...acc, [...last, curr]]
        : [...acc, ...(last ? [last] : []), curr];
    }, []);
```

Comment: This relies on the order of positive integer properties in an object in a very sneaky way. It won't work with any other kind of values.

Comment: the only thing you would need to do to is a reordering of the final array which is super easy to do with sort

Comment: Yes, you should do that. And use an array straight away, not object properties.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your code is very hard to read, and it would probably be better if you'd rewrite it somehow, but I will leave that up to you. One thing you can do, to remove this global variable, is to use a concept called higher order function.

```
const higherOrderFunction = () => {
    let counter = 1;
    const groupFunction = (currentValue, index, arr) => {
        nextNumber = arr[index + 1];
        if (currentValue === nextNumber){
            counter++;
        } else {
            if (counter > 1){
                let filledArray = new Array(counter).fill(currentValue);
                counter = 1;
                return filledArray;
            } else {
                return currentValue;
            }
        }
    }
    return groupFunction; 
};
```

You then get access to your groupFunction by calling the higher order function,
but the variable does not pollute your global scope:

```
let groupFunction = higherOrderFunction()
```